# NSToolbarItem add image buttons with no label? (macOS)

Tags: swift, macos

I'm creating a preferences window and here's what I wanna achieve:

In **Xcode**:

[image: Xcode]

Like Xcode's preferences window, these features are what I want:

- **Image button with flexible padding (Image above)**.
- **No NSToolbarItem's label (Let buttons take up all the vertical spaces)**.
- **After a button is chosen, keep its background (border) until I choose another**.

Below are snippets of what I've done by now:

```
// In my window controller

let toolbar = NSToolbar(identifier: "PreferencesToolbar")
toolbar.autosavesConfiguration = true
toolbar.allowsUserCustomization = false
toolbar.displayMode = .iconOnly  // This is not working since the label is still showing
toolbar.delegate = self
window?.toolbar = toolbar
```

```
// In toolbar delegate

func toolbar(_ toolbar: NSToolbar, itemForItemIdentifier itemIdentifier: NSToolbarItem.Identifier, willBeInsertedIntoToolbar flag: Bool) -> NSToolbarItem? {
    var item: NSToolbarItem?
        
    switch itemIdentifier {
        
    case .general:
        var image: NSImage!
        if #available(macOS 11.0, *) {
            image = NSImage(systemSymbolName: "gear", accessibilityDescription: nil)
        } else {
            image = NSImage(named: NSImage.preferencesGeneralName)
        }
        let button = NSButton(image: image, target: self, action: #selector(toggleView(_:)))
        button.identifier = .general
        button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 38).isActive = true
        button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 28).isActive = true
        button.title = ""
        button.imageScaling = .scaleProportionallyDown
        button.focusRingType = .none
        button.showsBorderOnlyWhileMouseInside = true
        item = NSToolbarItem(itemIdentifier: .general)
        item?.label = ""  // No label
        item?.view = button
            
    case .about:
        var image: NSImage!
        if #available(macOS 11.0, *) {
            image = NSImage(systemSymbolName: "info.circle", accessibilityDescription: nil)
        } else {
            image = NSImage(named: NSImage.infoName)
        }
        let button = NSButton(image: image, target: self, action: #selector(toggleView(_:)))
        button.identifier = .about
        button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 38).isActive = true
        button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 28).isActive = true
        button.title = ""
        button.imageScaling = .scaleProportionallyDown
        button.focusRingType = .none
        button.showsBorderOnlyWhileMouseInside = true
        item = NSToolbarItem(itemIdentifier: .about)
        item?.label = ""  // No label
        item?.view = button
            
    default:
        item = nil
    }
        
    return item
}
```

I set `item.label = ""` and you see, the label is unclickable but still takes up some space under my button. I also set `toolbar.displayMode = .iconOnly` but it's not working:

[image: Prf1]

Then after I added titles to my button and set `button.imagePosition = .imageAbove`, my image and title mixed together:

[image: Prf2]

Looks awful right? I wonder how can I achieve the effect like Xcode does. **My project's development target is 10.15, so I can't just use `.toolbar {}` in SwiftUI. :)**

---

Comment: Do it through the Interface Builder.

Comment: @ElTomato Hi it's you again! :) So can I do this programmatically? I don't really use storyboard...

Comment: Is the configration autosaved with titles? Try `toolbar.autosavesConfiguration = false`.

Comment: @Willeke Don't know what for but I tried just now, still no luck...

Comment: I tried your code and I don't see titles.

Comment: @RoyRao At least use a Storyboard/XIB to mock it out and see what it could look like. When you're happy with the result, look at what settings were used, and set those with code. Otherwise you're just going to waste your time fiddling with anchors and constraints blindly.

Comment: @Willeke If you're talking about my button's title, I didn't show it in my code above. I just simply set ```button.title = "General"```. The most tricky part is that how can I remove NSToolbarItem's label and let my custom buttons take up all the vertical space...

Comment: @Alexander I think you're right... I'll try it out later, thanks!

Comment: Can you hide the titles when `toolbar.allowsUserCustomization = true`?

Comment: @Willeke Already tried, no luck though...